# Is singing high in chest voice bad for you?

Tags: voice

If you know me, you'll know that I am a terrible singer when it comes to high notes, as I struggle to use head voice, instead using chest voice. I strain to use chest voice while singing high, and my voice gets a little scratchy after a few days. Is chest voice bad for you when it comes to high notes?

Comment: From what little research I just did it is not unless you strain yourself to do so. Straining your voice is damaging regardless of circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having to strain and your voice starts getting "scratchy" it's a good sign that you are doing some damage. This is a case where it would definitely be worth getting a couple of lessons from a good teacher to learn techniques for getting those high notes without strain

Answer (score 1):

If you strain your voice or have to "belt" out while singing in chest voice, then it is better to learn from a choir teacher or someone who can help you reach those high notes. You could damage your vocal chords if you strain too much.